# QGIS Modeller - Are there system variables

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-modeler

In a QGIS 3.2 model can we use system variables?

Basically I want the input filename to be used in the output filename.

So

```
inputName.shp -->run process-->inputName_processed.shp
```

In arcGIS it's %inputName% and the value comes from Get Field Value - http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/get-field-value.htm

===update

based on the answer from Erik -how do i use layer_name in the final column 'calculated' in this? i want it be the input name with '_processed' at the end.

[image]

Comment: For the field calculator `layer_property(layername, source)` gives you the source of the layer, and when running a batch process you may use the input layers name as a base for the auto-fill. Also, in the field calculator there are several other variables, e.g. `layer_name`.

Comment: @Erik thanks but please see further details on the issue above

Comment: I've seen this question asked many different ways and never clearly answered. People seem to address something about the algorithm in the model, as Erik has. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170480/qgis-modeler-use-input-filename-in-output-filename is the closest thing to a 'clear' answer, IMO